# Using a React component in a regular web page

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, requirejs

This is a very simplified version of my React component:

**my-panel.js (my-panel-bundle.js)**

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

class MyPanel extends React.Component {
  render () {
    <input type='text' />
  }
}

export default MyPanel
```

The full version is composed by several other components. I am using webpack to create a bundle file for the component. Now I want to use this component in an existing web application, which is not implemented using React. My challenge is, how do I load the React module, and create an instance of this component in a web page?

I have tried to use RequireJS, like this:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id='root'></div>
        <script src="require.js" data-main="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        react: 'react',
        reactDom: 'react-dom',
        myPanel: 'my-panel'
    }
})

require(['react', 'reactDom', 'myPanel'], function(React, ReactDOM, MyPanel) {
    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(MyPanel),
        document.getElementById('root')
    )
})
```

The code fails reporting that MyPanel is undefined. Can anyone please help me identify the missing pieces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you forgot the return value in render function of your MyPanel component.

```
class MyPanel extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <input type='text' />
  }
}
```

Coming to the main question. MyPanel is undefined because the path to the bundle is incorrect. Assuming that your project directory is something like the following:

```
- project/
    - index.html
    - index.js
    - bundle/
        - my-panel-bundle.js
    /... the rest
```

your require config should look like:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        react: 'react',
        reactDom: 'react-dom',
        bundle: 'bundle'
    }
})

require(['react', 'reactDom', 'bundle/my-panel-bundle'], function(React, ReactDOM, MyPanel) {
    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(MyPanel),
        document.getElementById('root')
    )
})
```

Alternatively, you don't actually need require.js if you use webpack. Instead of `export default ...`, put the ReactDOM render code:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(MyPanel),
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

after the class definition and include the bundle script in your html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id='root'></div>
        <script src="./bundle/my-panel-bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, and thank you for helping out. I made the changes you suggested but I still get the same error message:

Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Comment: that means your path is still incorrect. Can you tell me the structure of your react project?

Comment: Since this is a just a test project (for solving this issue), I initially had all the files in the root directory. Now I changed it so that the bundle-file is in a bundle folder. The rest of the files are still in the root folder, even react.js and react-dom.js.

I also changed the require call like you specified:

require(['react', 'reactDom', 'bundle/my-panel-bundle'], function(React, ReactDOM, MyPanel) { ... })

Comment: Sorry my bad, I forgotten to change myPanel to bundle. Try that and I think it should work.

Comment: Hmm... Still the exact same error. Do you have any more suggestions? Thanks again for your time!

Comment: I found a webpack setting - libraryTarget: 'amd' - that seemed relevant, but apparently is does not have any impact.

Comment: Can you try my second method without require.js? If you want to bootstrap a react project without all this hassle, I recommend using create-react-app.

Comment: Thanks @D-reaper, I ended up going for your second method. I will still investigate the first method as I think it has fewer disadvantages in practical use.

Comment: @FrankJusnes feel free to accept my answer too if it helps :)